# glossary / acronym ; list of pages / locations : ignore the actual list of acronyms

Tags: hyperref, glossaries, acronyms

I use the `glossaries` package with the `acronym` option.

When I create the list of acronyms, I have a list of locations (per entry): pages, and/or subsections.

The problem is that each (used) entry has the page of the list of acronyms in its list of locations... which I don't want.

How to ignore it?

---

## * MWE:

I'd like to have exactly the same but with no page numbers "1" in the list of acronyms (only "2"s or subsection references).

```
% If file save under 'mwe.tex', then compile it:

% pdflatex mwe
% makeglossarie mwe
% pdflatex mwe
% makeglossarie mwe
% pdflatex mwe
% pdflatex mwe

\documentclass[pdftex, letterpaper, 12pt, ]{article}

\usepackage[pdftex, breaklinks=true, ]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym, style=super3colheader, counter=page, hyperfirst=true, ]{glossaries} 
\makeglossaries

\renewcommand*{\pagelistname}{Location \\ }
\renewcommand*{\glsnumberformat}[1]{\textit{#1}}

\newacronym{rhs}{rhs}{right hand side}
\newacronym{lhs}{lhs}{left hand side}
\newacronym{RMS}{RMS}{Root-Mean-Square}
\newacronym{ESA}{ESA}{European Space Agency}

\begin{document}

\glsaddall

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, style=long3colheader, numberedsection=false, nonumberlist=false, ]

\section{Test}

\subsection{Blah}
here on the \gls{rhs} of this equation is the definition of the \gls[format=hyperbf, counter=subsection]{RMS}) that is given by the \gls*{ESA}.

\subsection{One more time}
here on the \gls{rhs} of this equation is the definition of the \gls[format=hyperbf, counter=subsection]{RMS}) that is given by the \gls*{ESA}.

\end{document}
```

---

## * PDF File produced:

[image: PDF File produced]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is caused by the `\glsaddall` command. It puts all acronyms in the document without generating text but creating a entry in the glossary. In your MWE all invisible acronyms are placed on the page of the glossary list.Have a look to the glossaries-user.pdf at page 53.